# Why is web scraping software recognized as human?

Tags: web-browser, spam, bot

I know that there are many open source projects that focus on web scraping and automation testing. The prominent ones are Puppeteer and Selenium. But these projects are not recognized as bots in recaptcha-like bot detection mechanism - at least during my experiments. For instance, I used Puppeteer and recaptcha for this experiment and all of the results returned as human, which are not true. My first assumption is that because these projects are cpu intensive, the malicious individuals won't use these software for malicious purposes.

I have read that recaptcha looks at browser headers etc. and if they are outdated/malformed then it may mark the user as bot. So, maybe, because puppeteer use the same browser that I use, recaptcha detects the puppeteer as human. But, browser headers are not good measurements, are they? They can be easily forged after all.

I don't think that attackers simply send http request thousands times to a website because if they do, recaptcha won't be able to load at the first place and will mark them as bots even without doing anything.

So, my questions are

1. Which software do attackers use for automated attacks/spams?
2. Against which software/attacks does recaptcha protect the website?

Comment: I think some details are required since you are basing your question on your tests. Which Recaptcha? Does your Recaptcha have exceptions for testing?

Comment: Recaptcha v3. But the question is general than that I think. It may be clarified as "do attackers use web scraping software like Puppeteer or are there any other dedicated software for malicious purposes?"

Comment: You have two big assumptions here: that these automated tools will always be "marked" as human, and that the recaptcha system doesn't make mistakes. I'm sure recaptcha looks at headers but this will only be one small indicator.

Comment: BTW, your first question is unanswerable. As for #2, recaptcha is aimed to stop automated bots in general, not specific kinds of software. It's just that the task is not easy. It actually looks primarily at behavioral markers, not the actual request

Comment: I could agree that first question is not answerable for those who did not wear black hat for pentest purposes but in this community there may be some members that have some experience in this field and at worst situation, I expected an answer like "they are developed in-house" or "100 lines of codes". For the second part, I know it is not that simple and naturally you mentioned "automated bot". So give me an example of automated bot. I want to simulate automated bot so that I can see myself "blocked" but it appears that puppeteer can evade recaptcha.

Comment: I think for the most part, ReCaptcha is behavior based and works best when inserted on many places on the site.  It needs to be configured to the webmaster's needs.  It does a good job of preventing abusive/malicious behavior without getting in the user's way.  It only goes so far, and isn't designed to protect a site from all attacks.  A service like Cloudflare has more comprehensive bot-detection and DOS prevention.  As for question 1, attackers will use whatever works against any particular target, and would probably "probe" using many different tools.